# on change select load another select options using jquery load

Tags: jquery, ajax, select, load

Here is my Javascript which is below a select box with the id of "course_name" and a div with an id of "dates"

```
<script>
$('#course_name').change(function() {
    url = "date_range.php?courseID=".$('#course_name').val();
  $("#dates").load(url)
});

</script>
```

when i call date_range.php?courseID=1 through my browser it displays the dates but the code above is not loading.

Comment: The `+` versus the `.` gets me all of the time when Im doing alot of JS and PHP. Lol. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
url = "date_range.php?courseID="+$('#course_name').val();
```

or better still,

```
url = "date_range.php?courseID="+parseInt($('#course_name').val());
```

the second one will always return a number so it's either 0 (zero) or above, if the #course_name value is a non numeric number it would return zero, otherwise returns the number... this is especially useful when you want to validate the value on the server.

Comment: @TommyArnold btw, you may want to check updated answer as this is a little better :)