# How to change second dropdownlist content based on item selected in the first ? (PHP)

Tags: php, selectedindexchanged, dropdown

I'm new to PHP.

I have a list of products in my database and I call them using:

```
$mysql = new MySqlManager();

$product = $mysql->getAllProducts();
```

Now I have two three dropdownlists: category, type, model ; of course each product belongs to one of these three categories.
What I want is that when the user selects the category (i.e. fridge, vaccum cleaner, portable devices, etc.), then a second dropdownlist appears (with or without refreshing the page, I don't care) and the user can choose between the type of product based on the category (i.e. if category was fridge, then in type you would find freezer, big fridges, small fridges, etc.). Then a third dropdownlist appears and the user can choose between the different models of types of products he chose before. I hope this explanation is clear, sorry if it is not.

Please help :)

Comment: I think you should use ajax

Comment: you can use ajax for this

Comment: duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686735/populate-one-dropdown-based-on-selection-in-another

Comment: possible duplicate of [on change select load another select options using jquery load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084202/on-change-select-load-another-select-options-using-jquery-load)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually no one helped me: I founded that it is possible to do it directly in PHP, with a POST method redirecting to other page and then coming back to the inital and displaying another dd list (simple if with session)